# Validar que un archivo existe en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Estoy comprobando que un archivo exista, dicho archivo se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el código que estoy ejecutando:

```
import os
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

print(os.path.isfile("../Fiunamfs.img")
```

El problema es que me dice que el archivo no existe en el directorio (`False`)

Incluso ya intenté con otras formas y me sigue dando `False`:

```
print(os.path.isdir("Fiunamfs.img"))
print(Path("Fiunamfs.img").is_file())
print(Path("Fiunamfs.img").exists())
```

Si pongo la ruta completa si me devuelve `True`, pero quiero evitar tener que poner toda la ruta porque el código debe funcionar en otras computadoras.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema no es que no estés usando la función correcta. De hecho algunas de las alternativas que indicas deberían funcionar. En particular, me centraré en la que usa la biblioteca `pathlib`, que es la forma recomendada y moderna de acceder al sistema de archivos hoy día.

Usando esa librería, el código relevante es este:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path("Fiunamfs.img").exists())
```

y debería devolverte `True` *si el fichero que indicas realmente está en la carpeta desde la cual se está ejecutando el script*. Pero creo que justamente ahí es donde radica el problema, y es que cuando ejecutas el script por alguna razón no estás en la carpeta en la que creías estar.

Prueba a ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
print(Path("Fiunamfs.img").absolute)
```

Y ahí verás la ruta completa al archivo al que estás **realmente** accediendo, y no al que creías estar accediendo. Es muy probable que descubras así que realmente estás en otra ruta, razón por la cual obtienes `False` en vez de `True` y en cambio poniendo la ruta absoluta te funciona correctamente.

La razón por la que estás en una ruta diferente a la que esperabas puede deberse a que estás ejecutando tu código desde un IDE mediante algún botón "Run" en cuyo caso el IDE podría estar lanzando el intérprete desde una ruta diferente a la carpeta en la que se halla el .py. O podría ser porque has tratado de empaquetar el programa usando `pyinstall` para después poder instalarlo en otras máquinas.

Si lo que quieres es acceder a ese archivo siendo la ruta relativa a la carpeta en la que se halla el .py, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
from pathlib import Path

ruta_absoluta = Path(__file__).parent / "Fiunamfs.img"
print(ruta_absoluta)
print(ruta_absoluta.exists())
```

Esto debería funcionar porque la variable `__file__` contiene siempre la ruta absoluta hacia el fichero `.py` que contiene el código que está siendo ejecutado. Usando `.parent` accedes a la carpeta, y después con `/ "Fiunamfs.img"` concatenas el nombre de fichero que te interesa, construyendo así la ruta absoluta al fichero, pero sin necesidad de especificarla, sino construyéndola dinámicamente, por lo que será portable a otras máquinas.

Comment: Justamente el problema era la carpeta, estoy usando VS code y la terminal se encontraba en la carpeta padre, por lo que no importaba que hiciera, siempre me daría ```false```. Alguien había respondido dándome una solución y le comenté lo mismo, pero creo que borró su respuesta.

Answer (score 4):

La forma correcta es usando `exists(path_al_archivo)`:

```
from os.path import exists

# Construir la ruta completa al archivo utilizando el directorio actual como base
if exists("arch.txt"):
    print('Archivo existe')
else:
    print('Archivo no existe')
```